# Show percentage completion between two dates in SQL?

Tags: sql

Been wasting a bit of time to do this exercise but unfortunately couldn't crack it!

I am attempting to show progression within a course in **SSMS** to later use for some fee calculations.

| Start Date | End Date | 01/08/2021 | 01/09/2021 | 01/10/2021 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 06/01/2021 | 14/10/2022 | £500 | £500 | £500 |
| 14/05/2018 | 13/08/2019 | £500 | £500 | £500 |
| 12/05/2020 | 20/05/2021 | £500 | £500 | £500 |
| 21/06/2019 | 21/12/2021 | £500 | £500 | £500 |
| 16/06/2021 | 23/09/2023 | £500 | £500 | £500 |
| 05/03/2018 | 05/09/2019 | £500 | £500 | £500 |

Basically, I need to show how far along within the course is 01/08/2021 (having the Start Date and End Date), then how far in the course is 01/09/2021, etc.

Uncertain about how to write this in a "smart" way, I've attempted doing:

```
CASE WHEN CAST('01/08/2021' AS DATE) < CAST([Start Date] AS DATE) THEN '0' ELSE DATEDIFF(DAY,[Start Date], '01/08/2021')/DATEDIFF(DAY,[Start Date], [End Date])*100 END AS [Progress]
```

but this has several issues. One for which I've had to add the CASE statement (some reference values were way before Start Date - thus the course has not started). Other issues that I couldn't solve are that it returns 0 for the example, returns 200 for Start Date 05/03/2018 and End Date 05/09/2019 - which I could forcibly hardcode as just 100 but I'd like to see if there's a more elegant way.

Also, it is there an alternative to re-running this and adding dates manually for every single column header? (ie: how can this be written in dynamic sql?)

**EDIT**: This is on SQL Server Management Studio, added a few more lines of example data

Comment: Please add a) your SQL version (e.g. MySQL, SQL Server, Oracle) and b) some sample data.

Comment: I don't quite understand what you are asking. Instead of all the £500 you want to show the percentage of the date in the date range? So 2021-01-06 to 2022-10-14 are 646 days. 2021-01-06 to 2021-08-01 are 207 days. 207 days of 646 days are 32%. So you want to show this value for the first row in the 2021-08-01 column?

Comment: @ThorstenKettner yes, for the purpose of the exercise the content of columns 3-5 is irrelevant; their headers are the only relevant information and the progress percentage can be a brand new column. And you are also correct on the desired output!

Comment: So apply the two `DATEDIFF` and divide. In SQL queries, columns are fixed. So, if you don't know which date columns you will need, there are two options: 1. Write a query to know the desired dates. Use these to construct another query with these columns and run it. (This is called dynamic SQL.) 2. Don't read the data in columns, but in rows and let your app build the grid in a loop.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner I assumed dynamic SQL would have been the elegant solution but the problem was my general lack of knowledge in it! I can read and understand it well enough when I see it in script but for the life of me I can't think of how to write this dynamically.

Comment: Dynamic SQL would not be my choice here. Dynamic SQL means nothing more than to write one SQL and use its results to build another. So take any programming language and send a query to the database to get the minimum and maximum date. Then use these two values and run a loop from start to end to add a column to the select list in your final query string. When you are done send that query to the DBMS and read the results into a grid.

Comment: I think it is much simpler to just read all rows with their starts and ends right away and loop through them. Everytime a row needs more columns, you just add them to your grid. I don't see any elegance in selecting only the minimum and maximum dates first, then building another query from them and bother the DBMS again. ;-)

Comment: @ThorstenKettner you are recommending a WHILE loop to create the columns correct? If I had to build this for a financial year (12 months) populating with the correct percentages for each month of progress - how would I go about it? I've gotten as far as declaring variables and setting them before getting stumped :(

Comment: Are you trying to do this in the DBMS? I wouldn't. I would just write an app in C# or whatever and retrieve the data and fill a grid. As far as I know, you *can* build queries dynamically in SQL Server, but as I don't use SQL Server, I don't know how this is being done there.